# Angular project does not load SCSS file in specific component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, sass

My Angular projects loads all the other components, but i tried to add this scientific calculator i found ([link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scientific-calculator?file=src/main.ts)) and the CSS does not load in a SCSS file even if it should not give this type of problems!

I already tried looking better at the source code to see if i missed something but found nothing!

HTML

```
<div class="p-1 form-group">
  <form method="POST" class="alert alert-secondary">
    <div class="w-100">
      <div class="row pb-1">
        <div class="col text-right">
            <span class="badge badge-info" *ngIf="statusMemory()">Mem: {{valueMemory()}}</span>

            <span class="badge badge-success" *ngIf="getOperand()!='';" [innerHTML]="getOperand()"></span>
            
            <span class="badge badge-warning" *ngIf="getRadians(); else badgeGrads">Rad</span>
            <ng-template #badgeGrads><span class="badge badge-info">Grad</span></ng-template>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><input type="text" placeholder="0" #inputField value="{{getFormula()}}" class="form-control text-right"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="addBracket('(');">(</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="addBracket(')');">)</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="clearMemory();">mc</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="sumToMemory();">m+</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="deductToMemory();">m-</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="readMemory();">mr</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="clear();">C</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('invert',-1);">&#177;</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('percent',-1);">%</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-xl btn-info" (click)="setOperation('/');">&divide;</button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else fs"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="secondScreen();">2<sup>nd</sup></button></div>
        <ng-template #fs><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="secondScreen();">1<sup>nd</sup></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('pow',2);">x<sup>2</sup></button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('pow',3);">x<sup>3</sup></button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="setOperation('pow');">x<sup>y</sup></button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else yx"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('pow_base','e');">e<sup>x</sup></button></div>
        <ng-template #yx><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="setOperation('yx');">y<sup>x</sup></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else x2"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('pow_base',10);">10<sup>x</sup></button></div>
        <ng-template #x2><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="singleton('pow_base',2);">2<sup>x</sup></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addSymbol('7');">7</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addSymbol('8');">8</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addSymbol('9');">9</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-xl btn-info" (click)="setOperation('*');">&times;</button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('div',1);"><sup>1</sup>/<sub>x</sub></button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('sqrt',2);"><sup>2</sup>&radic;x</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('sqrt3',1/3);"><sup>3</sup>&radic;x</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="setOperation('sqrt');"><sup>y</sup>&radic;x</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else log"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('ln',2.7);">ln</button></div>
        <ng-template #log><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="setOperation('log');">log<sub>y</sub></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else log2"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('lg',10);">lg</button></div>
        <ng-template #log2><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="singleton('lg',2);">log<sub>2</sub></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addSymbol('4');">4</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addSymbol('5');">5</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addSymbol('6');">6</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-xl btn-info" (click)="setOperation('-');">&minus;</button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('factorial',1);">x!</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else asin"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('sin',1);">sin</button></div>
        <ng-template #asin><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="singleton('asin',1);">sin<sup>-1</sup></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else acos"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('cos',1);">cos</button></div>
        <ng-template #acos><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="singleton('acos',1);">cos<sup>-1</sup></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else atan"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('tan',1);">tan</button></div>
        <ng-template #atan><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="singleton('atan',1);">tan<sup>-1</sup></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="addSymbol('2.718281828459045',true);">e</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('ee',1);" title="Exponencial view of number">EE</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addSymbol('1');">1</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addSymbol('2');">2</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addSymbol('3');">3</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-xl btn-info" (click)="setOperation('+');">&#43;</button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="getRadians(); else Grads"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-warning" (click)="setRadians();">Rad</button></div>
        <ng-template #Grads><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="setRadians();">Grad</button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else asinh"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('sinh',1);">sin<sup>h</sup></button></div>
        <ng-template #asinh><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="singleton('asinh',1);">sinh<sup>-1</sup></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else acosh"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('cosh',1);">cos<sup>h</sup></button></div>
        <ng-template #acosh><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="singleton('acosh',1);">cosh<sup>-1</sup></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex" *ngIf="!getScreen(); else atanh"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('tanh',1);">tan<sup>h</sup></button></div>
        <ng-template #atanh><div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="singleton('atanh',1);">tanh<sup>-1</sup></button></div></ng-template>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="addSymbol('3.141592653589793',true);">&#x213C;</button></div>
        <div class="col d-none d-lt-flex"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="singleton('rand',1);">Rnd</button></div>
        <div class="col-2 mycol-2"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addSymbol('0');">0</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success"(click)="addSymbol('.');">,</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="calculate();">=</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mycol-2 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
.col {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.col-2 {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.btn-xl {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 0.9;
}
.btn-sm {
    border-radius: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 420px) {
    .d-lt-none {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .d-lt-inline {
        display: inline !important;
    }
    .d-lt-inline-block {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
    .d-lt-block {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .d-lt-table {
        display: table !important;
    }
    .d-lt-table-row {
        display: table-row !important;
    }
    .d-lt-table-cell {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
    .d-lt-flex {
        display: -ms-flexbox !important;
        display: flex !important;
    }
    .d-lt-inline-flex {
        display: -ms-inline-flexbox !important;
        display: inline-flex !important;
    }
    .mycol-2 {
        flex: 0 0 20%;
        max-width: 20%;
    }
}
```

I tried searching for some missing parts but found nothing useful

Comment: What kind of error you get? Is there any log or error thrown by the browser?

Comment: nothing pertaining this unfortunately